# Closing laptop lid slows/hangs wifi

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, laptop

There are 4 other PC's in the house all connected to the same wifi.  These 4 PC's have been experiencing intermittent internet hangs and slowdowns, though the worst affected is laptop and the PC next to it.

After several calls and visits by Time Warner techs, we've come to establish that there is no problem with the router, cable modem, cable connection and so on.  We also established through trial and error that shutting the lid on the affected laptop will slow the internet connection speed considerably.

Lid open, the laptop hits 55mbps download regularly on speedtest. When closed, it fluctuates from 8-12mbps.  The remaining PC's in the house regularly hit 20-25mbps on speedtest and the network doesn't seem affected by the laptop lid position.

So we know the laptop lid being closed affects that laptop connection speed but so far I do not understand how it can affect the entire network?  Or perhaps this is just a coincidence.

Right now I'm not sure what the next steps could be in order to fix this connectivity issue?  I'm also unsure why the laptop gets 55mbps and the other 4 PC's on the network only get 25mbps?  I'm currently in the process of leaving the laptop turned off and checking for connectivity issues on the other 4 PC's but because it's intermittent it is hard to tell for sure.

Does anyone have any advice, suggestions or answers?

Comment: Is your power setting for lid shut on the laptop set to "Do Nothing" or do you have it go in to Standby?

Comment: Like above, go to power options and change closing the lid to "do nothing". Also uninstall or disable any software from the manufacturer that deals with power management. Often these types of application manipulate the power options on the fly and can do some pretty crazy things by default such as throttling the CPU, network or even forcing HDD to spin down faster in an effort to make the machine run longer or more power efficiently. There is also a setting in windows for WIFI that allows the WIFI to be turned off or controlled different with lid down you should disable.

Comment: The speed difference between laptop and regular machine could simply be positional or interferrance related (antenna is better positioned on laptop).

Comment: The close lid option is "do nothing" already because I have the laptop connected to a larger monitor.  All power management options on the cards are turned off.  There has been no problem with this setup for the last 9 months or so, this intermittent problem started happening maybe 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Any changes to physical location of router/PC? New (location of) cordless phones, microwave ovens, baby monitors etc.? Any tinkering with router wifi settings (don't know if TW even allows that)?

Comment: No changes whatsoever, no new devices which could interfere.  Running out of ideas!

Comment: I've got the exact same symptoms, and I've found that my internet speeds actually get reduced *proportionately to the angle of my laptop lid as it closes*. I would think it's a signal interference issue of some kind, but my upload speeds are at full force--higher than my download speeds! Changing the angle of the closed laptop relative to the ground has no impact.

Answer (score 0):

I also only started experiencing the exact same issue weeks ago, except my laptop seems to lose connectivity entirely. I haven't yet found a solution, but what you might be experiencing is a dual band issue. A router than is not dual band can only go as fast as it's slowest device. Try removing your laptop from the network entirely by disabling WiFi on it and see if this resolves your problem. If it does, and your problem only persist when your lid is closed, check if your router is dual band or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm currently experimenting with the laptop completely removed from the area and kept switched off. I'll check out the dual band issue you mention as well.

Comment: stripling warrior has an interesting comment where he found that the angle of the lid accepts the speed! so maybe try a wifi adaptor.. maybe the internal wifi isn't really designed to work well when the lid is closed or half closed!